# Can't understand what <>0 means

Tags: c#, excel

Hi I'm trying to understand a formula and write it in c# but so far I haven't managed to understand what this formula does, could someone please explain?

```
if(if(c57=> d57;g57;h57)<>0;(((if(c57>=d57;d57;c57))*100/11))/(if(c57 >=d57;c57;d57)));(100/11)))
```

what really gets me lost is the <>0, I've googled some time but so far haven't found what it does. Please could someone explain?

Comment: are you sure that this is a valid (excel) formula? with properly nested parentheses? fwiw, `if(c57>=d57;d57;c57)`, `if(c57>=d57;c57;d57)` are equivalent to `min(c57,d57)`, `max(c57,d57)`, resp.

Comment: nevermind i just updated it

Comment: Still not valid. It should end with `/(IF(C57>=D57,C57,D57)),(100/11))`. Too many parentheses.

Comment: Also the edit really changes the meaning of the original question. It used to sort of look like It could all be simplified to `C57<D57`

Comment: @Ramhound The question states *Hi I'm trying to understand a formula and write it in c#*

Comment: @mattytommo - I only caught that after my comment was posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<>0` is the equivalent of "not equal to Zero"

In this case it may be equivalent to "not False", for example taking part of the formula:

`if(c57=> d57)<>0`

Evaluate whether C57 is NOT >= D57

Comment: There are systems where 0 is true though

Answer (score 5):

`<>` means "not equal", as in ≠. Also known as `!=` in most programming languages.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the language, but in a majority of them `<>` means 'does not equal'.

Answer (score 2):

`<>` is the *not equal to* operator.

`a1<>0` is the same as `a1!=0` in C#.

See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/calculation-operators-and-precedence-HP010342223.aspx?CTT=1 for the documentation on Excel's calculation operators

Answer (score 2):

`<>` is the inequality operator, meaning that `a <> b` is `a is not equal to b`. Which would be written as `a != b` in C#.

As far as I know, the only languages that use `<>` are VB/VbScript (which is what Excel syntax is based on), SQL, BASIC and Pascal. In T-SQL you can actually use `!=`, but it's non-standard SQL so `<>` is preferred.

Comment: I think VB.NET also uses `<>` for value-type inequality checks

Comment: @jbabey You're right, added. Makes sense because Excel syntax is based on VB anyway :).